# Where are all these DLLs coming from?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a basic ConsoleApp1, and these references:

[image]

**Why do I get all these DLLs in bin folder after compilation?**

- ConsoleApp1.exe
- ConsoleApp1.pdb
- ConsoleApp1.exe.config
- Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
- Microsoft.Synchronization.xml
- Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.dll
- Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.xml
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Common.ClientInterfaceLayer.dll
- SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Common.Core.dll
- SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Common.DataServiceLayer.dll
- SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Common.ObjectDefinitions.dll
- SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Common.Objects.dll
- SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Common.Shared.dll
- SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjectDefinitions.dll
- SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.SecurityObjects.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll

**What do System.Web.XXX dlls have to do with it?

What do Microsoft.Synchronization.XXX dlls have to do with it?**

Comment: If  it´s really a console-app I suppose you can eliminate most of the references. Just try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe you selected a template you didn't expect too when you created the project.

Comment: On the screenshot you can see I used Resharper to remove all unused references.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies. One of your included references needed one of those assemblies to run, therefore it brought it in for you. Also of note, it doesn't check to see what functions you've called to see if it really needs them. It blindly includes them just to be safe.

Comment: Looks like it, but System.Web?? This has nothing to do with Web or Razor